# Filling a layout dynamically crashes the application without errors

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

When I try to open this new activity through a button on a previous layout the app crashes with no apparent reason.
My code is this :

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


private   int limitsImages[] = {R.drawable.onelimits, R.drawable.twolimits, R.drawable.threelimits, R.drawable.fourlimits, R.drawable.fivelimits, R.drawable.sixlimits,
        R.drawable.sevenlimits, R.drawable.eightlimits, R.drawable.ninelimits, R.drawable.tenlimits};

private   String answersLimits[] = {"-9", "2", "1/10", "1/6", "1/2", "12", "1", "2/3", "5/6", "1/4"};

private String choicesLimits[][] = {{"-19", "19", "-9", "2"},{"0", "-2", "Does not exist", "2"}, {"Does not exist","1/5","0","1/10"},{"1/6","1/5","1/4","1"}
,{"1","1/2","0","Does not exist"},{"0","4","12","10"},{"0","1","1/2","2/3"},{"2/3","1","3/2","0"},{"1","2/6","5/6","4"},{"1/4","1"
        ,"Does not exist","4"}};


private  TextView questionNum;
private  TextView questionTxt;
private  ImageView questionImage;
private  CheckBox choiceOne;
private  CheckBox choiceTwo;
private  CheckBox choiceThree;
private  CheckBox choiceFour;

private static int testIdentifier=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

    questionNum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionNumber);
    questionTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionText);
    questionImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.questionImage);
    choiceOne = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.choice1);
    choiceTwo = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.choice2);
    choiceThree = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.choice3);
    choiceFour = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.choice4);

    //choicesLimits[4][3]=getString(R.string.doesntexist);
    //choicesLimits[9][2]=getString(R.string.doesntexist);



    startLimitsQuestion(testIdentifier);




}

public void startLimitsQuestion( int questionNum) {
    this.questionNum.setText(questionNum+1+"/10");
    questionTxt.setText(getString(R.string.limitsQ));
    questionImage.setImageResource(limitsImages[questionNum]);
    choiceOne.setText(choicesLimits[questionNum][1]);
    choiceTwo.setText(choicesLimits[questionNum][2]);
    choiceThree.setText(choicesLimits[questionNum][3]);
    choiceFour.setText(choicesLimits[questionNum][4]);


}
```

Sub Question:I have been troubled a bit if my initialization and declaration before the onCreate() method is correct.

edit: Layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    tools:context="com.example.learnmath.Main2Activity"
    >


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button5"
        android:text="@string/quadratics" />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/derivatives"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="18dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/timetostart"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button6" />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/limits"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button6"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:onClick="limitsQuiz" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/mathtest"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginRight="46dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="46dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button6" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/tests"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:shadowColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView2" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/index"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:onClick="homePage" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your logcat

Comment: Have you declare your activity in manifest with intent filter

Comment: can you add your layout file

Comment: No I have not declared my activity in manifest with intent filter. Why would that be helpful and is it something I should do? I just start my activity with the command
    startActivity(new Intent(Main2Activity.this,Main3Activity.class));

Comment: I have resolved your problem and I answered. Please check @ArisEleftheriadis

Comment: @ArisEleftheriadis If you have not registered your activity in Manifest then register and build the code again and start activity .

Comment: @ArisEleftheriadis : You must declare your activity in Manifest. Haven't you??

Comment: No I haven't since the other activity that I created did not have such problems. Is it because I am trying to tamper with it?

Comment: I just googled and noticed that the activity is mentioned in Manifest without me ever tampering with it. Isn't the declaration of each activity done automatically?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141939/discussion-between-hiren-shah-and-mike-m).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that you clicked and then it crashed. So some problem will be there in the onclick. We need to follow your code from onclick. The above snippet is just showing the first question display and these are correct except the test identifier is not incremented.

Please do post  full class code of that snippet. Also do give logcat error

What i could guess is some where the error should be in registering activity to manifest or error durimg onclick where your accessing arrays. May be arrayoutofbounds too.

Comment: So how to post my logcat should I restart android studio run the app once replicate the error then upload it because it is too big at the moment? I have not finished implementing this class so this is the whole snippet

Comment: It was an array out of bounds I found the error on the logcat. I do not know why it went unnoticed through the other logs. Silly mistake after all..

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved your problem. The app theme you declared in your **AndroidManifest.xml** is not appropriate. As you are extending the **AppCompatActivity** in your activity, you need to use the **Appcompat** theme for your particular activity or application. 
Change your current app theme to **`android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"`** in **AndroidManifest.xml** file will resolve your problem.
**Note::** Your initialisation and declaration is perfect and your onClick method is not the issue. This AppTheme is the only issue. Tell me if you didn't get me.

Comment: Changed the theme still I get a crash. edit : as I mentioned above I have not declared my activity in Manifest. So I guess I changed the theme only for my main activity and I should just declare the activity on manifest then change the theme of this specific activity?

Comment: Yes you need to first declare that activity in your AndroidManifest.xml file and then you need to change the theme as I suggested. your problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebase crash library to report Crash to detect crash if you are not able to crash in logcate

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/